# USB Drives and phones aren't mounted automatically

Tags: usb, mount

Recently, my USB drives and phone stopped mounting automatically. I've tried using `dconf-editor`, but it is already set to automount.

Both are detected by `lsusb`, as seen in the output:

```
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 12d1:107e Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. P10 smartphone
Bus 003 Device 009: ID ffff:5678 USB Disk 2.0
```

I can mount the USB drive using the `Gnome Disks` application, but I cannot mount the files to be seen by the Android device. (Note that I already selected to have the Android device share files). The output of `sudo dmesg` is as follows for the phone:

```
[  845.407094] usb 1-2.3: USB disconnect, device number 10
[  847.167548] usb 1-2.3: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[  847.274349] usb 1-2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=107e, bcdDevice= 2.99
[  847.274354] usb 1-2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  847.274356] usb 1-2.3: Product: BND-L34
[  847.274358] usb 1-2.3: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
[  847.274359] usb 1-2.3: SerialNumber: 4AV7N18A09002815
[  847.327597] usb-storage 1-2.3:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  847.327779] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-2.3:1.1
[  848.359974] scsi 3:0:0:0: CD-ROM            Linux    File-CD Gadget   0404 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  848.360333] sr 3:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[  848.360665] sr 3:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
[  848.362076] sr 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[  848.362132] sr 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[  849.503349] usb 1-2.3: USB disconnect, device number 11
[  849.895774] usb 1-2.3: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[  849.998481] usb 1-2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=107e, bcdDevice= 2.99
[  849.998486] usb 1-2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  849.998488] usb 1-2.3: Product: BND-L34
[  849.998489] usb 1-2.3: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
[  849.998490] usb 1-2.3: SerialNumber: 4AV7N18A09002815
[  850.047854] usb-storage 1-2.3:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  850.047995] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-2.3:1.1
[  851.080212] scsi 3:0:0:0: CD-ROM            Linux    File-CD Gadget   0404 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  851.080597] sr 3:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[  851.080976] sr 3:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
[  851.082553] sr 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[  851.082652] sr 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
```

The only way I can access my phone files is via an application called `android-file-transfer`, and it can see those files, so I'm not sure where the disconnect is between nautilus and it.

This may or may not be realted, but I can't access the files in my Trash anymore, saying `Sorry, could not display the contents of "trash:///": Operation not permitted.`

Comment: If you can not access trash you have a problem you need to fix before worrying about mounting USB. They maybe should be the focus of the question and a change to the title.

Comment: I exactly have the same issue, no trash nor usb recognized. It has been a few month with Ubuntu 23.04 and I'm not sure if it's the upgrade or my fault. What's your ubuntu version?